# Linked Server to Oracle suddenly failing

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have a linked server connection from SQL 2008 and it has been working fine for months. Today, with no configuration changes, the linked server is failing with TNS errors from SQL Server...."ORA 12154 TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified".

The Oracle DBA who helped me install the Oracle drivers has tested the TNS ping from the server, and so is convinced the Oracle side is working...but he can't advise on SQL Server side.

We are stuffed without this, and nothing changed from the SQL end...it just decided not to work today....

Regards

I

Comment: I think this one belongs in the severfault or at dba

Comment: Post all the tns errors, otherwise this is impossible to solve

Comment: AllI get from SQL Server is OraOLEDB.Oracle for linked server x returned message Ora 12154 TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified.  SQL server error then:MSG 7303 cannot initialise the data source object of OLEDB Provider OraOLEDB.Oracle for linked server X.